# MutationObserver detecting element appereance and changing of element's value

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I intend to use MutationObserver on observing the appearance and changing of element's value, but to be honest I'm not sure how this should be implemented.

[image]

The target of MO would be `div.player-bar` and what I'm trying to accomplish is to detect when `el-badge__content` appears in page and when `el-badge__content` element value is changed (for example instead `1` would change to `2`).

Please note that `el-badge__content` appears at the same time with the creation of `div.new-bar` and many times `div.new-bar` would not be present in the page, that's why I need to listen to `div.player-bar`.

Is this possible? So far I was thinking of something like this:

```
var target = document.getElementsByClassName('player-bar')[0];
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.forEach(function(addedNode) {
      var e = addedNode.document.getElementsByClassName('el-badge__content')[0];
      if (e) {
        console.log("Element appearance/changed")
      };
    });
  });
});

observer.observe(target, config);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mutation` is a [MutationRecord object](https://devdocs.io/dom/mutationrecord) that contains the array-like `addedNodes` NodeList collection that you missed in your code, but it's not an array so it doesn't have forEach. You can use ES6 for-of enumeration in modern browsers or a plain for loop or invoke forEach.call.

A much easier solution for this particular case is to use the dynamically updated live collection returned by getElementsByClassName since it's superfast, usually much faster than enumeration of all the mutation records and all their added nodes within.

```
const target = document.querySelector('.player-bar');
// this is a live collection - when the node is added the [0] element will be defined
const badges = target.getElementsByClassName('el-badge__content');
let prevBadge, prevBadgeText;

const mo = new MutationObserver(() => {
  const badge = badges[0];
  if (badge && (
      //  the element was added/replaced entirely
      badge !== prevBadge ||
      // or just its internal text node
      badge.textContent !== prevBadgeText
  )) {
    prevBadge = badge;
    prevBadgeText = badge.textContent;
    doSomething();
  }
});
mo.observe(target, {subtree: true, childList: true});

function doSomething() {
  const badge = badges[0];
  console.log(badge, badge.textContent);
}
```

As you can see the second observer is added on the badge element itself. When the badge element is removed, the observer will be automatically removed by the garbage collector.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, still learning MO. The above code works for the appereance of el-badge__content, but when the value changes from 1 to 2, I get nothing in console + console shows "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'observe' on 'MutationObserver': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'." :(

Comment: I've modified the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help. One little error, dunno if it's a big problem. When I click on the element, the entire `div.new-bar` (including the descendants and `el-badge__content`) gets removed from the DOOM tree and that moment I get in console "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
    at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:11:27)"